# Converting Hex CANbus message to GPS long/lat

Tags: python, gps, hex, data-conversion, can-bus

I´m looking for some help converting CAN packets from a PCAN-GPS unit to long/lat GPS coordinates.
For example i receive Data=90F98E400A0045 for longitude and the package is in the following format:
[imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2CvB.png)

So I get the Degree and Indicator part which match my location from Google Maps but when I try to convert the hex value to a floating point I either get enormous or tiny float values that are not longitude values.

I wrote this code (and some other variations) in Python. My location is somewhere in germany ;)

```
s = ['E8', '5F', '8F', '40', '0A', '00', '45']
con = []
x = ""



def tohex(hex_string):
    return ''.join('{0:04b}'.format(int(c, 16)) for c in hex_string)


def long(str):
    min = str[:32]
    vorz = min[:1]
    mat = int(min[1:24], 2)
    exp = int(min[24:32], 2)
    l = (2**exp) * float("0."+mat.__str__())
    deg = str[32:48]

    print(int(deg,2))

    return l


for e in s:
    con.append(tohex(e))
    x += tohex(e)

print("%.100f" % long(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The more efficient solution is to use the `struct.unpack()` function.

Solution for Python 3.5.x

1- store the binary data recorded from CANbus in a bytes object.

```
tCanLng1=bytes([0xE8, 0x5F, 0x8F, 0x40, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x45])
```

2- define the format specifier of the `GPS_PositionLongitude` structure.

> For `GPS_LongitudeMinutes` (float) is `'f'` (4 bytes).
>
> For `GPS_LongitudeDegree` (int16) is `'h'` (2 bytes).
>
> For `GPS_IndicatorEW` (char) is `'c'` (1 byte).
>
> End for the byte alignment (little-endian) add as first specifier
>   `'<'`

3- Then perform the unpack of the CANbus binary data as follow:

```
>> vCanLng=struct.unpack('<fhc',tCanLng1)
>> vCanLng
(4.480457305908203, 10, b'E')
```

4- And the result for your position in Germany is:

```
GPS_LongitudeMinutes = vCanLng[0] = 4.480457305908203
GPS_LongitudeDegree = vCanLng[1] = 10
GPS_IndicatorEW = vCanLng[2] = 'E'
```

> GPS_PositionLongitude = 10° 4.480457305908203 E = (10 +
>   (4.480457305908203/60))° E = **10.0746742884318 ° East**.